# Why is GTP, rather than ATP, used in nuclear transport?

Tags: biochemistry, energy-metabolism, intracellular-transport

Why is GTP used for nuclear transport and not ATP, given that ATP hydrolysis is used to drive most cellular energonic reactions?

Comment: Welcome to Biology SE! This appears to be a homework question. Homework questions are off-topic on our site unless you have shown your attempt at an answer. For more information see [our homework policy](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework).

Comment: Would be very interesting to know, if there was some systems-biology reason (that would extend beyond a superficial answer such as the most prominent nuclear transport proteins using using GTP). (note: ATP can be required for some aspects of nuclear transport, in particular for RNA)

Comment: @vkehayas  I think this is an open question in biochemistry, and as such not likely homework (or else a very tricky assignment :)  To my knowledge at least, it is not understood why different nucleotides are preferred as energy source by different systems -- if indeed there is any advantage to this scheme at all.  Protein synthesis and gluconeogenesis (PEPCK) also uses GTP, btw.

Comment: @Roland I am aware that this is not a resolved issue. I was attempting to nudge the OP to give us some background on why this question is interesting to them and what research they have done already.

Comment: I have edited the question slightly and removed the homework tag as I don't think it relevant. (I have gone on to provide an answer of sorts.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Disclaimer**

Although this question appears to be either unclear or unanswerable (or both), and shows no evidence of research on the poster’s part, I have chosen to address one aspect of it to emphasize a general concept. This, despite the fact that my knowledge of nuclear transport processes is minimal.

**Brief Answer**

GTP, rather than ATP, is used for nuclear–cytoplasmic transport via importins and exportins, because this process involves one of a large family of ‘G proteins’ that — as their name implies — operate through the use of GTP. Whereas ATP is generally used to drive endergonic molecular reactions, the hydrolysis of GTP in G-protein cycles can be thought as a device to terminate a molecular process. Whether G proteins adopted GTP rather than ATP merely by chance or for a biological reason is a matter of speculation.

**NTP hydrolysis — for fun or profit?**

It would appear that the question relates to protein-transporting ‘importins and exportins’, which I learn from the Wikipedia article on [nuclear transport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_transport) are regulated by the small G protein, Ran. When complexed to GTP, Ran facilitates the export of proteins by exportins, a process that is terminated by hydrolysis of GTP to GDP. The GDP-bound form facilitates the import of proteins by importins, a process that is terminated by GTP displacing the GDP.

So if we consider the role of the hydrolysis of the nucleotide triphosphate — here GTP — it is clearly not to supply thermodynamic energy for an endergonic process such as muscle contraction, light generation or a chemical reaction with a +ve ΔG:
[image: Use of ATP to drive endergonic processes]

Rather, it is to produce a conformational change in a protein which allows the termination of a process. This termination is generally through the GDP-bound form of the G protein (grey) interacting with some other protein (black):
[image: GTP hydrolysis and G proteins]

This diagram is deliberately simplistic so that the general features of G-protein action can be seen. However, I think it illustrates the same point made in Berg *et al.* [Section 15.6](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK22455/). Other examples are signal transduction of hormone action via cyclic AMP and binding of aminoacyl-tRNA to the ribosome.

**Why do G proteins use GTP?**

This ‘choice’ of GTP in the original ancestral G protein could have been mere chance, that was subsequently reflected in other G proteins that arose through gene duplication and divergence. That would imply that, at least, it was not disadvantageous. Or as the oldest G proteins are perhaps those involved in protein biosynthesis — a process still catalysed by a ribozyme — the choice of GTP might have reflected an RNA base-pairing interaction in the ‘RNA world’.

Alternatively one might suggest a biological rationale for separating two types of energy-requiring processes — perhaps by regulation of the enzyme that catalyses the conversion of ATP to GTP, [dinucleoside-phosphate kinase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nucleoside-phosphate_kinase). However I am not aware of any evidence to support this idea.

**Hydrolysis of GTP in other contexts**

As mentioned in a comment by @Roland, there are instances where GTP is used to drive endergonic reactions (phosphoenolpyruvate carboxykinase) in a manner analogous to the use of ATP, but this is quite different from hydrolysis of GTP in G proteins. I do not believe that any convincing rationale for this has been propounded, nor for the similar exceptional use of [UTP in glycogen synthesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTP%E2%80%94glucose-1-phosphate_uridylyltransferase) and [CTP in phospholipid synthesis](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK22405/). This question has been discussed in [another post](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/11286/why-is-atp-the-preferred-choice-for-energy-carriers/14044#14044).